# BufferedIo.read() argument in partitial() method no keyword argument error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new in python and trying some kind of this code and got "TypeError: read() takes no keyword arguments".

```
from functools import partial

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('class.jpg', 'rb') as file:
        for data in iter(partial(file.read, n=1012), b''):
            print(data, len(data))
```

Without 'n=' it works ok. According to a [dcumentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedReader), there is some unlear statement "read([size]".
So this method could take an argument, which pycharm mark as variable "n", but how does it works in low level and why error rises, could someone explain please?

Comment: `.read()` only takes positional parameters.  Use `partial(file.read, 1012)`.

Comment: Greetings! Thanks for rply, i undrestand it, cause traceback gives almost the same answer. It's unclear what arguments used in read method is it sequence as a '*args' or something else? Adn where does it possible to look at the sources of this method?

Comment: The parameter is the maximum number of characters to read (you may get less, usually because there aren't that many characters left in the file).  If omitted, it reads the entire file.